# Facebook Open Graph meta tag for date of an event?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to create meta tags for Facebook sharing option with the open graph protocol. I have different tags like in the following snippet:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="business.business" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.mywebsite.com/journal" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://mywebsite.com/images/stories/beautifulimagelikeyou.jpg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="My website" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Description of my wonderful page" />
```

**I am looking for a meta tag to add the scheduled date of an event** (e.g. a concert) and there seem to be nothing other than `xxx:release-time` or `xxx:published-time` ([checked on the documenation](http://ogp.me/)) and ideally I am looking to add something like

```
<meta property="og:date" content="2016-06-06" />
```

or

```
<meta property="event:date" content="2016-06-06" />
```

has anyone ever used this kind of tag? because both [og docs](http://ogp.me/) and [facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph) do not seem to include this kind of tag, and I don't know how to go about it. thank you.

Comment: If you want to set up a page for a single event, then `business.business` is the wrong type for that to begin with, I’d say. (That’s for regular businesses, with repeating/period opening hours.) There is no pre-defined OG object for an “event” - so even if you squeeze the date into the meta info somewhere, most likely no one (including Facebook) will care. Perhaps you’d be better off creating your own custom object type.

Comment: @CBroe Hi, thanks for the suggestion. the `business.business` was just an example and not the actual type I inserted. However, you made a good point because even in the type tag there is no such thing like event.